# Why is apply param thisArg being omitted when I used Array.prototype.slice?

Tags: javascript

Here the code:

```
Function.prototype.curry = function() {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
    args = slice.apply(arguments), // no thisArg ? arguments are the sec param [argsArray]
    that = this;
    return function() {
        // thisArg: null
        return that.apply(null, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments)));
    }
}
```

Above is what I understand. So why does `that.apply` have a `null` param, while the `slice.apply` doesn't have one?

And when I changed it to `args = slice.apply(null, arguments)`, It threw an error which said:

> Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.slice called on null or undefined

Where am I wrong about `Function.prototype.apply()`?

Comment: Just FWIW, that's a *terrible* version of `curry`, because A) It screws up `this`, and B) It creates an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) called `args`. Wherever you got it, I would suggest looking elsewhere.

Comment: @janje: I wouldn't think so, unless it's misquoted; I'd expect Crockford to know better than to create an implict global. He may not care about `this` (depending on when the code is from; he used to use `this`, doesn't anymore), but the implicit global wouldn't pass jslint.

Comment: @janje: That suggests to me that the `;` after `Array.prototype.slice` is *also* a `,` in Crockford's version (which would fix the issue with `args` and `that`). Anyway, not the first time I've had an issue with something from Crockford, not going to be the last. :-) (He can be forgiven for creating an enumerable property, if this was from _The Good Parts_; he didn't have a choice back then.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: And worse: this `curry` method doesn't even [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), it's doing partial application.

Comment: "*no thisArg?*" - wrong. `arguments` is passed here as the *thisArg* - and the second parameter, the *optional* arguments array, is omitted. You could however have done `slice.apply(arguments, [0])` which is like `arguments.slice(0)` (instead of `arguments.slice()`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, the semicolons r my mistake. Already fixed.

Comment: Thank u @Bergi , that makes sense !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `slice.apply` and `that.apply` calls in that function have different purposes.

Just a quick recap: `Function#apply` accepts up to two arguments: The value to use as `this` during the call to the original function, and any array-like object which has the arguments (if any) to pass to the function.

The `slice.apply` calls, such as this one:

```
args = slice.apply(arguments);
```

...are passing `arguments` as the first argument, so `slice` gets called with `this` referring to the `arguments` object and with no arguments at all. This is a fairly common idiom for converting the array-like arguments object into a true array. (In modern code with ES2015, we'd probably use `args = Array.from(arguments);` instead.)

The `that.apply` call doing something else entirely: It's calling the function object that `curry` was called on, passing it the arguments supplied to `curry` followed by the arguments supplied when the curried function was actually called. It passes `null` as the first argument, the value to use as `this` during the call, which means the original function will be called with `this` referring to the global object (if this is in loose mode) or `null` (in strict mode`).

---

Not to bikeshed it, but that's not a great implementation of `curry` if it's been quoted correctly:

1. *(You've fixed this in the question.)* <s>It creates two [implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): `args` and `that`, which is a pretty bad idea. [janje suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773117/why-is-apply-param-thisarg-being-omitted-when-i-used-array-prototype-slice?noredirect=1#comment63016900_37773117) it may be a misquoted version of Crockford's `curry` from *The Good Parts*; if so, the `;` after `Array.prototype.slice` and after `slice.apply(arguments)` should be a **`,`** instead:</s>

   ```
   Function.prototype.curry = function() {
       var slice = Array.prototype.slice, // <== comma here
           args = slice.apply(arguments), // <== comma here
           that = this;
       return function() {
           return that.apply(null, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments)));
       };                                 // Crockford probably didn't leave this semicolon out
   };                                     // Or this one
   ```
2. It blocks `this` when calling the original function; instead, it should use the same `this` that hte curried function was called with.
3. It's creating an *enumerable* property on `Function.prototype`; all the other methods on `Function.prototype` are *non-enumerable*, probably best to keep it that way.

Instead:

```
(function() {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
    Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "curry", {
        value: function() {
            var originalFunction = this;
            var args = slice.apply(arguments);
            return function() {
                return originalFunction.apply(this, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments)));
            };
        },
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
})();
```

Example:

```js
"use strict";

// Define it
(function() {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
    Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "curry", {
        value: function() {
            var originalFunction = this;
            var args = slice.apply(arguments);
            return function() {
                return originalFunction.apply(this, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments)));
            };
        },
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
})();

// Demonstrate it
function foo() {
  console.log("this.answer:", this && this.answer);
  console.log("args:", arguments);
}

var obj = {answer: 42, foo: foo.curry("curried")};
obj.foo("supplied during call");
```

There are optimizations one could make (it's not strictly necessary to create a new array on each call to the curried function), but they don't really buy much.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation ! And there's one extended question: How could i know the [native codes] in `Array.prototype.slice` method ? I wanna check where and how `this` refers to the `arguments` object. Is there a way to check this out ?

Comment: @Soon: Each JavaScript engine will have its own implementation of `slice`, but the specification [lays out exactly what it's supposed to do](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.slice). If you want to look at an implementation, V8's copy (V8 is the JavaScript engine in Chrome and NodeJS) is [in this file](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/array.js).

Answer (score 2):

`.apply` sets context and arguments for a function:

```
my_fn.apply({}, [1,2,3]);

function my_fn() {
  console.log(this); // {}
  console.log(arguments); // [1,2,3]
}
```

`slice.apply(arguments);` is a hack to convert an array like object to an actual array, actually it could also have been `.call(arguments);` since call works almost like `.apply`:

```
my_fn.call({}, 1,2,3); // <- no array but more arguments

function my_fn() {
  console.log(this); // {}
  console.log(arguments); // [1,2,3]
}
```

So `that.apply(null, ...` just doesn't set a context for the function `that`. While `Array.prototype.slice` expects to work on an array like object and will fail if it gets no context.